# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function" from using timeout with a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, timeout

I want to do a callback with the calculator if successful, and I want it to catch the "Too High" error. But now when it throws the error all i get is "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function". No idea what I am doing wrong here

```
const calculator = (number, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try { if (number > 3) Error('Too high')
      callback(null, number);
    } catch (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    }
  }, 888);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It would appear that you're calling `calculator` without passing it a function, but since you haven't shown the call, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Side note: `Error('Too high')` just creates an `Error` object, it doesn't *do* anything with it, You probably meant `throw Error('Too high')` (or `throw new Error('Too high')`, which does the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are passing a callback as a param when calling the calculator function. If you want to catch the error `Too High` what you can do here instead is add the condition to the callback function you're passing as a param to the calculator function and return it from there since here your if condition is returning undefined. Actually, instead of adding the if one-line condition, use the `&&` operator in the callback function, you are passing to return an error if a number is greater than 3. And just like T.J Crowder is saying you use `throw Error('Too High')`.